# Finding the Basis of a Subspace $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is spanned by a series of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

The Question goes as follows:

Find a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is spanned by the following vectors

$$ (1,0,0) \ \ \ \ (1,1,0) \ \ \ \  (4,1,0) \ \ \ \  (0,-1,0)\ \ \ \ $$

I tried similar problems that reduced to similar dimensions (Screenshot attached below) but I can't seem to be able to solve this question. Could someone help me solve this problem and tell me why I was wrong in the first two attempts?

Screenshots here:

[image: Attempt 2]

[image: Attempt 1][1]]

My work is quite messy I'll try to add it. But I essentially created the augmented matrix, reduced it to RREF, and found that two vectors could be express by the two other vectors. For Q1, $v3_ = 3(v_1) + 1(v_2)$ and $v_4 = 2(v_1) - 2(v_2)$. For Q2, $v_3 = v_1 + v_2$ and $v_4 = v_1 - v_2$.

Comment: Perhaps it would good to include your attempt, how did you choose your answers previously.

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh My work is quite messy I'll try to add it. But I essentially created the augmented matrix, reduced it to RREF, and found that two vectors could be express by the two other vectors. For Q1, v3 = 3(v1) + 1(v2) and v4 = 2(v1) - 2(v2). For Q2, v3 = v1 + v2 and v4 = v1 - v2.

Comment: Pay attention to the location of the zeroes.

Comment: @CyclotomicField The final row is a zero row?

Comment: @UT-HJ is it an implicit assumption that the basis components be orthogonal?  Otherwise any 2 linearly independent vectors will span a 2 dimensional space, perhaps I'm misinterpreting the question?

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome The basis vectors are not orthogonal? None of their products = 0. Are you saying I should choose the option "All of the Above"? And for which question? Edit: This is an early year university question not one the incredibly complex engineering questions that are usually on here so assume a level of simplicity :)

Comment: How did you rule out the possibility that the answer is All of the Above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Q1 and Q2, all the options suggest that the dimension of the subspace is $2$. As long as the two vectors are not multiple of each other, they can form a basis.

Remember that basis is not unique and we should not stop at the first correct answer.